# Closed projects in Eclipse don't appears in a working set in a package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer, working-set

I recently installed a new version of eclipse (2018-09), and faced with this problem. So let say we have 4 opened projects A,B,C and D:
[4 projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ALV.png)

And then we create new working set *WS_01* with: **View Menu** (down arrow icon in package explorer) > **Select working set...** > **New...** > **Java** > **Finish**. And we add projects **A** and **B** in that set.

Then, if I select **View Menu** > **WS_01**, package explorer will show only projects A and B. The problem is, if I close project B, it will disappears from explorer. Even if I unchecked option **Closed projects** from **View Menu** > **Filters ...** , project B will be still missing.

But if I go back to **View Menu** > **1_Windows_working_set**, then I can see closed folder of project B:
[project B is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0A0J.png)

Comment: In Filters, did you also uncheck _Non-Java Projects_? Can you reproduce this issue with a _Resource_ instead of a _Java_ working set? There is no version _18-19_. Did you mean _2018-09_? Please show also a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant on 2018-09. I tried with _Resource_ set, but I got the same result. Here you can see all steps that I tried: [imgur_post](https://imgur.com/a/RT38i67)

Comment: If you choose in the _Package Explorer_ view menu _Top Level Elements > Working Sets_, the closed projects are shown and _Closed Projects_ works as expected, right? That seems like a bug to me. Please report it to Eclipse.

Comment: Oh thanks. It works if I choose _Top Level Elemensts>Working Sets_ ([imgur](https://imgur.com/a/Hw8wkQM)). I didn't even think about this option. I agree with you that my original problem is probably a bug in new version of eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a **bug in the *Package Explorer* of Eclipse 2018-09**: see [Eclipse bug 538216](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538216)

You can use one of the following as workaround for this bug:

- Use the ***Project Explorer*** instead of the *Package Explorer*
- In the *Package Explorer* view menu choose ***Top Level Elements > Working Sets***

Comment: The ticket has been closed referencing this stack overflow article as the fix?

Comment: @MichaelJoyner The status of Eclipse bug 538216 (which was reported by you) is still _new_. The Eclipse platform project lead was not able to reproduce this issue (comment #1), so I added the conditions which are required to reproduce this issue and a link to this question here (comment #2).

Comment: I think I have just run into this issue with Eclipse 2019-12 :/ Thanks for the workaround using "Project Explorer", that actually worked for me.